# How to make notices pop up as jquery on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, notice

I have a user controller with the following code.

```
  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to '/', notice: 'Thank you for signing up for Beta.'
    else
      redirect_to '/', notice: 'That was an invalid or duplicate email address. Please try again!'
    end
  end
```

How can I make these pop up with jquery?

Answer (score 4):

Just put this at the bottom:

```
<script>
  <% if params[:notice].present? %>
    alert(<%= params[:notice] %>);
  <% end %>
</script>
```